# ChangeDetectorRef destroyed state

Tags: angular, routes, angular-changedetection

We have Jumpto action of one component element to another component. In this case the `ChangeDetectorRef[destroyed]` is always true because of it I'm unable to force `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` function

home.component

```
function(){
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboardComponent']);
 //BehaviorSubject
 this.behSubject.subscribe();
}
```

dashboard.component

```
 ngOninIt(){
    //BehaviorSubject
    this.behSubject.subscribe(
      //function call 
       this.setValues()
     )
 }

  setValues(){
    ChangeDetectorRef[destroyed] // Always true.
  }
```

is it carrying `home.component` destroyed instance to `dashboard.component` ? how to over come this ?

Comment: Do your stuff before navigating away, as navigation actually destroys the component and its view.

Comment: but why `dashboard.component.ts` carrying `ChangeDetectorRef` reference of home component

Comment: Don't know, your code is ugly, so I assume you didn't copy/pasted it but quickly wrote it. Provide a [mcve] reproducing this issue, and I might be able to help you figure that out.

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I see it. Wait.

Comment: Try with `behSubject.subscribe(this.setValues.bind(this))`. This is a context/scope error.

Comment: @trichetriche when I getting false, `BehaviorSubject` not emitting. don't know why it behaving like this.